# Detect whether local browser supports ICE trickle

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

To support ICE-trickling with arbitrary clients, it is recommended that the signalling mechanism also supports signalling for trickle support. Mine does that; a peer can include a flag whether it supports trickling in the initial signalling handshake, so the remote peer can decide to trickle.

The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to detect whether the *current browser* supports ICE-trickling or not, so it can set that flag correctly. I've tried to use this as a detection mechanism:

```
typeof RTCPeerConnection.prototype.addIceCandidate == 'function'
```

Is this reliable and the best there is, or is there a better API or method to query for *local* support for ICE-trickling?

Comment: All the browsers that support WebRTC support trickling.

Comment: That appears to be true with all relevant browsers we tested with. However, at some point in the past that appeared to not be true. Most information on trickling is rather dated and from that controversial time period. Is it guaranteed anywhere which browsers support it; or again, some way to detect support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All modern WebRTC end-points *must* support Trickle ICE.

[JSEP section 5.2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-jsep-18#section-5.2.1) says:

> An "a=ice-options" line with the "trickle" option MUST be added, as specified in [[I-D.ietf-ice-trickle](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-jsep-18#ref-I-D.ietf-ice-trickle)], Section 4.

Additionally, from my reading of the WebRTC spec, for a browser to be [conformant](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#conformance), it *must* implement [addIceCandidate](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcpeerconnection-addicecandidate()) etc.

All browsers that support WebRTC today support trickling. The following returns `true` in Firefox (Chrome appears not to signal this correctly, but rest assured it supports trickling):

```js
new RTCPeerConnection().createOffer({offerToReceiveAudio: true})
.then(offer => console.log(offer.sdp.includes('\r\na=ice-options:trickle')))
.catch(e => log(e));
```

Interestingly, there's a [`pc.canTrickleIceCandidates`](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcpeerconnection-cantrickleicecandidates) attribute you can use to detect if the *remote* peer supports trickling, presumably to support connecting to legacy systems. The following produces `true` in Firefox (`undefined` in Chrome, which needs to catch up to the spec):

```js
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

pc1.onicecandidate = e => pc2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => pc1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);

pc1.onnegotiationneeded = e =>
  pc1.createOffer().then(d => pc1.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
  .then(() => pc2.createAnswer()).then(d => pc2.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
  .then(() => console.log(pc1.canTrickleIceCandidates))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

pc1.createDataChannel("dummy");
```